# Algorithms bounds and functions describing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

ok so basically i need to understand how i can compare functions so that i can find big O big theta and big omega for algorithms of a program

my mathematics background is not very strong but i have the foundations down

and my question is

is there a mathematical way to find where two functions will intersect and eventually one dominate the other from some point n

for example if i have a function

2n^2 and 64nlog(n) [with log to base 2]

how can i find at which values of n, 2n^2 will upper bound( hope i used the correct term here) 64nlog(n) and also how to apply this to any other function

is it just simply guess work?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the intercepts of the two functions.  So set them equal to each other and solve for n.  Or just plot them and get a rough idea of the intercepts so you know at what size of data you should switch between each algorithm.  Also, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/EquationSolving.html) has useful function solving and plotting tools too, just in case you are a bit rusty on math.

Answer (score 0):

Big O, Big Theta, and Big Omega are about general sorts of growth patterns for *algorithms*.  Each algorithm can be implemented an infinite number of ways.  Each *implementation* may have a specific execution time, which relates to the Big O of the algorithm.  You can compare the execution-time-per-input-size of two implementations of an algorithm, but not for an algorithm by itself.  Big O, Big Theta, and Big Omega say next-to-nothing about the execution-time of an algorithm.   As such, you cannot even guess a specific intersection point of where one algorithm becomes faster, because such a concept makes no sense.  We can discuss intersection points in theory, but not in detail, because it has no value for algorithms, only implementations.

It's also important to note that Big O (and similar) have no constant factors, like your functions do.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 0):

You can divide out an `n` on both sides, and a common factor 2, and then solve this:

```
32 log(n) <= c n  for n >= n_0
```

Let's say `c = 32`, because then it's `log(n) <= n` (which looks nice), and `n_0` can be 1.

But this sort of thing has already been done. Unless you are in CS class, you can just say that O(n log n) is a subset of O(n<sup>2</sup>) without proving it, it's well-known anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For big-O, big-Theta, and big-Omega, you don't have to find the intersection point. You just have to prove that one function eventually dominates the other (up to constant factors). One useful tool for this for example is L'Hopital's rule: Take the ratio of the two running time functions and compute the limit as n goes to infinity, and if the limit is infinity/infinity then you can apply L'Hopital's rule to get that the limit of the ratio is equal to the limit of the ratio of derivatives, and sometimes get a solution. For example this shows that log(n) = O(n^c) for any c > 0.